# Rake just one migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, rake

I'm trying to run just one migration out of a whole bunch in my rails app.  How can I do this? I don't want to run any of the migrations before or after it. Thanks.

Comment: This would be a convenient rails feature: add a `STEP=n` argument to `db:migrate` (where `n` is the number of migrations to run, just like there is for `db:rollback`) - then you could do `rake db:migrate STEP=1` or `rake db:migrate STEP=2`, etc.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

`rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=xxxxxxx`, but that will run the `down` and then the `up` step. You could do this in conjunction with commenting out the down step temporarily.

Comment: Hmm, http://blog.stonean.com/2007/12/18/rake-dbmigrateredo/, ::redo doesn't seem to take a VERSION argument.

Comment: It works, I tested it.

Note that the article is from TWO THOUSAND AND SEVEN. Rails changes a lot during that time.

Comment: Then why should Stackoverflow display outdated info? If you now run `rake -T` there's no task called `db:migrate:redo`

Comment: @pedrorolo: This is not outdated. This task has no description and so it will not show up in `rake -T`.

Comment: @pedrorolo: `db:test:prepare` also doesn't show up on that list.  God I'm late to the party.

Comment: The undescribed tasks don't display on that list. That's a "feature" of Rake.

Comment: use rake -P to list all tasks along with their dependencies, even the ones without descriptions

Comment: To expand on what Ryan says, if the table has been dropped from the database outside of Rails, `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=my_version` may do _nothing_, because the schema_migrations table still says it is has been run. In the same situation `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=my_version` may _fail_ because it cannot drop the table. In this case, comment out the `down` method in the migration temporarily and re-run `rake db:migrate:redo...`

Comment: And to expand what @Leo says, if the migration is defined with def change, then change it to def self.up in addition to the above.

Comment: Noteworthy, `VERSION` is just an environment variable so it can come first in the command or even set previous to the command: `VERSION=xxxxxxx rake db:migrate:redo`

Answer (score 76):

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=1234567890
```

similarly `rake db:migrate:down` to take a specific migration down. You can get a list of available rake tasks with `rake -T`.

Comment: The `VERSION` mentioned here is the integer value at the beginning of each of your migration files (which is just the timestamp of when it was created). For example,  `VERSION=20150720023630`.

Comment: The versions are displayed nicely with rake db:migrate:status

Comment: Noteworthy, `VERSION` is just an environment variable so it can come first in the command or even set previous to the command: `VERSION=1234567890 rake db:migrate:up`

Answer (score 25):

I've had to run a single migration that changed and needed to be re-run independently of all other migrations. Fire up the console and do this:

```
>> require 'db/migrate/your_migrations.rb'
=> ["YourMigrations"]
>> YourMigrations.up
=> etc... as the migration runs
>> YourMigration.down
```

More usefully this could be put into a rake task etc.

Comment: This worked awesomely. You can also just copy-paste the code from the migration into the console to define the class (and this allows for manual manipulation if needed, if you just made a mistake on Dev, for example). If you defined a reversible migration with `change`, run `YourMigrations.migrate(:up)` instead (or `:down` too!)

Comment: you might have to `require "#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/your_migrations.rb"`

Answer (score 19):

`rake db:migrate:up VERSION=version_no`

Will migrate( add) specific migration script

`rake db:migrate:down VERSION=version_no`

Will delete specific migration script

Answer (score 14):

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=20098252345
```

give that a try.

Comment: I think this will run any migrations up to the one you specified.

Comment: close, but that also runs any migrations before the specific migration.

Comment: I don't think you should/want to run only one migration without considering the ones before it. A migration is a representation of the databases structure as it relates to the code at a given point in time , and thus the migrations before it are necessary. If you only want to run _one_ migration it's likely you didn't write the proper up/down operations to keep the migrations functional... it's a bad habit to only write your up migrations.

Comment: Noteworthy: `VERSION` is just an environment variable so it can come first in the command or even set previous to the command: `VERSION=20098252345 rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 5):

```
rake db:migrate:redo version='xxxx'
```

Remember to put the quotation mark around xxxx, xxxx is the timestamp (or Migration ID) for your migration.

You may check the timestamps (Migration ID) for the previous migrations you've done by using

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the answer by korch above, `require` did not work for me, but `load` did.  To be concrete, for the migration file:

```
    class ChangeMinQuantityToRaces < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        change_column :races, :min_quantity, :integer, :default => 0
      end
    end
```

in the console typing

```
    > load 'db/migrate/30130925110821_change_min_quantity_to_races.rb'
    > ChangeMinQuantityToRaces.new.change
```

worked for me.

```
    > Race.new.min_quantity # => 0
```

This was for ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux] and Rails 3.2.13.

Answer (score 3):

Adding my 2¢ to this because I ran into this same issue:

If you absolutely want to run a migration over again without creating a new one, you can do the following:

`rails dbconsole -p
devdb=# delete from public.schema_migrations where version = '20150105181157';`

And rails will "forget" that it ran the migration for 20150105181157.  Now when you run db:migrate it will run it again.

This is almost always a bad idea though.  The one instance where it could make sense is if you have a development branch and you haven't fleshed out your migration yet and want to add some things to it in development.  But even then it's better to make your migration 2-way so you can properly rollback and retry repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

There's got to be a way to run the migration class via the console.  I can't seem to get the migrations code to be recognizable.

However, as the comments indicate, it's preferred to run the migrations in order.  Use:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=##########
```

Copy and paste your code in the migration to script/console?

Answer (score 1):

I have a utility method that makes this very easy in development. I find that it helps me avoid creating too many migrations--normally I modify migrations until they have been deployed.

http://fullware.net/index.php/2011/05/26/easily-load-rails-migrations-for-console-execution/

Answer (score 0):

I use this technique in development when I change a migration a significant amount, and I don't want to migrate down a ton and lose any data in those along the way (especially when I'm importing legacy data that takes a long time that I don't want to have to re-import again).

This is 100% hackish and I would definitely not recommend doing this in production, but it will do the trick:

1. Move migration that you want to re-run out of its directory to a temporary place
2. Generate another migration with the same name
3. Copy/paste the original migration code into the newly generated migration file
4. Run the new migration
5. Delete the newly generated migration file
6. Edit your schema migrations to remove the most recent value
7. Restore the old migration file