# Rails: ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need some help getting my Cloud 9/Rails environment working again for an online course I'm working on through Upskill. I ran into a problem with one section and ended up rolling back to a previous commit. However, since I did that, I've run into some database errors I haven't been able to resolve.

Here is what I get when I try to access my app:

> ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
>   Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

I've tried the suggested method to resolve it, but it hasn't worked, nor have a dozen other suggestions I've found in other threads with a similar message.

Below is what I see when I run rails db:migrate:status. So I believe maybe it has something to do with the third item there.

### Status   Migration ID    Migration Name

up     20170331144924  Create contacts

up     20170406172755  Devise create users

down    20170410151911  Add devise to users

I am really lost but just hoping to get back to where I was so I can continue with the lessons. Thank you.

Comment: Will you detail the "half-a-dozen other suggestions"? We can't help very well if we don't know what you have or haven't tried.

Comment: Most of the suggestions have involved deleting the database and recreating it, which I've tried several times but I still get the same error. I have tried several variations of rails db:migrate to no avail. So just not sure what else to try.

Comment: If you don't care about the db data, you may just need to `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`.  Or, you may need to delete that file, take a look in the db/migrate folder and post what's in there.  It looks like it wants to run that migration.

Comment: You can also do `rake db:schema:load` and just delete the migrations files.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm getting closer but when I run rake db:migrate I get this message:

== 20170410192514 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL

Comment: From that error message, it looks as if you are missing a migration that is supposed to create the users table. Are you sure you aren't missing a migration somewhere, that you either deleted or forgot to write?

Comment: I am now missing the Devise create users table somehow. I'm not sure how to get it back. I tried running the commands the course instructed when installing Devise but that didn't seem to work. 

The information I used to install Devise was at this [link]( http://upskillcourses.com/courses/119763/lectures/1746936)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm just going to go back to a previous branch before I got to Devise and see if I can just start from Square One.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

```
rake db:test:purge
rake db:test:prepare
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a specific migration which is down like this? [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331367/rake-just-one-migration)

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20170410151911
```